# USQL Array of Array to flat CSV

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have an assembly that returns a

```
SQL.ARRAY<SQL.ARRAY<string>>
```

I need to flatten this to a csv, not getting the right result.

Here is what it looks like in U-SQL, if I create the array of arrays in that:

```
DECLARE @boardA1 SQL.ARRAY<string> = new SQL.ARRAY<string>{"111", "PASS", "0"};
DECLARE @boardA2 SQL.ARRAY<string> = new SQL.ARRAY<string>{"222", "PASS", "0"};
DECLARE @boardA3 SQL.ARRAY<string> = new SQL.ARRAY<string>{"333", "PASS", "0"};

@boards =
    SELECT *
    FROM(
        VALUES
        (
            new SQL.ARRAY<SQL.ARRAY<string>>{@boardA1, @boardA2, @boardA3}
        )
             ) AS t(boards);

@result =
    SELECT n.value AS Board
    FROM @boards
         CROSS APPLY
             EXPLODE(boards) AS c(value)
         CROSS APPLY
             EXPLODE(c.value) AS n(value);


OUTPUT @result
TO "result1.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

I get this output:

```
"111"
"PASS"
"0"
"222"
"PASS"
"0"
"333"
"PASS"
"0"
```

but I want this output:

```
"111","PASS","0"
"222","PASS","0"
"333","PASS","0"
```

What am I doing wrong? Any input appreciated!

Comment: Just an observation on the test data, each "column" of the array is the same structure suggesting it should actually be a row.  Is that just an artifact of your sample data?

Answer (score 1):

`@result2 =
    SELECT "\"" + string.Join(",", c.board).Replace(",", "\",\"") + "\"" AS Boards
    FROM @boards
    CROSS APPLY EXPLODE(boards) AS c(board);`

`OUTPUT @result2
TO "result2.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting: false);`

See examples under `ARRAY<ARRAY<string>>` from [Explode (U-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621306.aspx)

Comment: I tried that earlier, but it makes one string with comma separated values, and not comma separated strings. It maked this "111,PASS,0" instead of this "111","PASS","0"

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using the ordinal of the array you want, eg

```
@result =
    SELECT 
        x.board[0] AS a,
        x.board[1] AS b,
        x.board[2] AS c        
    FROM @boards
         CROSS APPLY
             EXPLODE(boards) AS x(board);
```

With this approach you can specify the column names explicitly and `quoting` behaves as expected.  The downside of this approach is that you have to know how many "columns" there are in the array.